# Python: Pandas DataFrame Manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, deep-learning

## Problem

I have a dataframe with `image_ids` and their respective `hash_values`. The columns represent the difference of that `image_id` w.r.t. other image ids as shown below:

[image]

These differences have been calculated to find which images are similar. The images having difference value less than 15 are considered as similar images.

## Objective

I want to obtain the dataframe with only unique image_ids i.e., delete the image_ids which are similar and only keep one of them.

### Example

As an example, in the dataframe images `1.jpg` and `2.jpg` are similar as their difference is `33` which is greater than `15` but images `3.1.jpg`, `3.2.jpg`, `3.3.jpg` are similar as their difference values are less than 15.

### Desired Output

The desired output should be the dataframe with only the image_ids as `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.1.jpg`.
`3.2.jpg` and `3.3.jpg` should be deleted as they are similar.

I wrote the below code, but it is removing any image having a similar value i.e., it removes `3.1.jpg`, `3.2.jpg`, `3.3.jpg` all of them from the dataframe.

```
# For every image_id, find the column values having value < 15 more than once and delete respective rows

def remove_duplicates(df):
    
        for i in range(len(df.image_ids)):
            clean_df = df.drop(df[df[f"diff_{df.image_ids[i]}"] < 15].index)
    
        return clean_df

clean_df = remove_duplicates(df)
```

The output of the code is:
[image]

As it can be clearly observed that the image `3.1.jpg` is absent in the dataframe whereas it should be present.

How to fix this?

Comment: "keep one of them". You just need the first one? Are all of the images' names follow the same pattern such as `number.jpg` or `number_number.jpg`?

Comment: No, the real `image_ids` are different. Here only for example purposes I have numbered them like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I have come up with. I firmly believe it's not the best idea, but might be a solution to your problem:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({"image_ids": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.2.jpg", "3.1.jpg", "3_3.jpg"]})
checkList = []
newDf = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  id = row["image_ids"]
  m1 = re.search(r"^(\d+)\.jpg$", id)
  m2 = re.search(r"^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.jpg$", id)
  if m1:
    if m1.group(1) in checkList:
      continue
    else:
      checkList.append(m1.group(1))
      newDf = newDf.append(row)
  elif m2:
    if m2.group(1) in checkList:
      continue
    elif m2.group(2) == "1":
      checkList.append(m2.group(1))
      newDf = newDf.append(row)
```

Note that, to have an example data, I wrote `df` dataframe. You have to change this line to load your dataframe.

##### Explanation

In this code, I have used [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to extract the id of each image. The first regex will catch the image's name which has a pattern like `5.jpg`. The second regex will capture if the image's name is something like `52.3.jpg`. Having appended the ids to a variable named `checkList`, I check if the image id has been selected before.

Comment: Hi, can you add a bit of explanation on the logic?

Answer (score 0):

If the difference columns for the images that have been removed isn't needed, dropping that image's difference column is a simple solution.

```
def remove_duplicates(df):

    for i in range(len(df.image_ids)):
        # This is the column that we want to drop
        col = 'diff_' + df[image_ids].iloc[i]

        clean_df = df.drop(df[df[f"diff_{df.image_ids[i]}"] < 15].index)

        # Dropping the column
        clean_df = clean_df.drop(columns=col)

    return clean_df
```

Note: The code might not work as I believe you're deleting all of the similar images at the same time. But I believe you can fix this by only deleting only the image at the current index whilst iterating and not deleting the other images.
I didn't do this myself as I didn't understand this line

```
clean_df = df.drop(df[df[f"diff_{df.image_ids[i]}"] < 15].index)
```

Still, removing only the current index's image and not the other similar images is a trivial task but I'm too lazy to do that from scartch.